# Xtext serializing model with references

Tags: serialization, xtext, scoping

I have a hard time figuring out, what am I doing wrong. A simplified example, of what I'm trying to do:

**The DSL:**

```
Model: elements += ModelElement*;
ModelElement: Greeting | Person;
Person: 'person' name = ID;
Greeting: 'hello' person = [Person];
```

**The code to serialize a model:**

```
val factory = MyDslFactory.eINSTANCE

val model = factory.createModel

val bob = factory.createPerson
bob.name = "Bob"

val greetBob = factory.createGreeting
greetBob.person = bob

model.elements += bob
model.elements += greetBob

val injector = Guice.createInjector(new MyDslRuntimeModule)
val serializer = injector.getInstance(ISerializer)
// Error happens here:
val result = serializer.serialize(model)
```

Now when this code runs, the `ImportedNamespaceAwareLocalScopeProvider` kicks in, and throws the following exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.xtext.scoping.impl.ImportedNamespaceAwareLocalScopeProvider.getResourceScope(ImportedNamespaceAwareLocalScopeProvider.java:95)
    at org.eclipse.xtext.scoping.impl.ImportedNamespaceAwareLocalScopeProvider.getScope(ImportedNamespaceAwareLocalScopeProvider.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.xtext.scoping.impl.ImportedNamespaceAwareLocalScopeProvider.getScope(ImportedNamespaceAwareLocalScopeProvider.java:87)
    at org.eclipse.xtext.scoping.impl.AbstractDeclarativeScopeProvider.delegateGetScope(AbstractDeclarativeScopeProvider.java:72)
    at org.eclipse.xtext.scoping.impl.AbstractDeclarativeScopeProvider.getScope(AbstractDeclarativeScopeProvider.java:102)
    at org.eclipse.xtext.serializer.tokens.CrossReferenceSerializer.serializeCrossRef(CrossReferenceSerializer.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.xtext.serializer.acceptor.SequenceFeeder.getToken(SequenceFeeder.java:454)
    at org.eclipse.xtext.serializer.acceptor.SequenceFeeder.accept(SequenceFeeder.java:214)
    at test.serializer.MyDslSemanticSequencer.sequence_Greeting(MyDslSemanticSequencer.java:65)
    at test.serializer.MyDslSemanticSequencer.createSequence(MyDslSemanticSequencer.java:33)
    at org.eclipse.xtext.serializer.acceptor.SequenceFeeder.acceptEObjectRuleCall(SequenceFeeder.java:299)
    at org.eclipse.xtext.serializer.acceptor.SequenceFeeder.acceptRuleCall(SequenceFeeder.java:325)
    at org.eclipse.xtext.serializer.acceptor.SequenceFeeder.accept(SequenceFeeder.java:239)
    at org.eclipse.xtext.serializer.sequencer.BacktrackingSemanticSequencer.accept(BacktrackingSemanticSequencer.java:400)
    at org.eclipse.xtext.serializer.sequencer.BacktrackingSemanticSequencer.createSequence(BacktrackingSemanticSequencer.java:449)
    at test.serializer.MyDslSemanticSequencer.sequence_Model(MyDslSemanticSequencer.java:75)
    at test.serializer.MyDslSemanticSequencer.createSequence(MyDslSemanticSequencer.java:39)
    at org.eclipse.xtext.serializer.impl.Serializer.serialize(Serializer.java:85)
    at org.eclipse.xtext.serializer.impl.Serializer.serialize(Serializer.java:108)
    at org.eclipse.xtext.serializer.impl.Serializer.serialize(Serializer.java:122)
    at org.eclipse.xtext.serializer.impl.Serializer.serialize(Serializer.java:51)
    at test.generator.MyDslGenerator.doGenerate(MyDslGenerator.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.xtext.builder.BuilderParticipant.handleChangedContents(BuilderParticipant.java:515)
    at org.eclipse.xtext.builder.BuilderParticipant.handleChangedContents(BuilderParticipant.java:505)
    at org.eclipse.xtext.builder.BuilderParticipant.doGenerate(BuilderParticipant.java:490)
    at org.eclipse.xtext.builder.BuilderParticipant.doBuild(BuilderParticipant.java:259)
    at org.eclipse.xtext.builder.BuilderParticipant.build(BuilderParticipant.java:217)
    at org.eclipse.xtext.builder.impl.RegistryBuilderParticipant$DeferredBuilderParticipant.build(RegistryBuilderParticipant.java:158)
    at org.eclipse.xtext.builder.impl.RegistryBuilderParticipant.build(RegistryBuilderParticipant.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.xtext.builder.impl.XtextBuilder.doBuild(XtextBuilder.java:189)
    at org.eclipse.xtext.builder.impl.XtextBuilder.incrementalBuild(XtextBuilder.java:167)
    at org.eclipse.xtext.builder.impl.XtextBuilder.build(XtextBuilder.java:95)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$2.run(BuildManager.java:734)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:206)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:246)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$1.run(BuildManager.java:299)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:302)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuildLoop(BuildManager.java:358)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.build(BuildManager.java:381)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.doBuild(AutoBuildJob.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.run(AutoBuildJob.java:241)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
```

Meaning, (i think), that it can't resolve a scope, and the only place, where this could happen is the `Greeting` rule's `person` reference.

Now if I'm writing a scope provider manually, the reference gets resolved without a problem, and it serializes fine.

```
class MyDslScopeProvider extends AbstractDeclarativeScopeProvider {
    //A dummy scope provider
    def scope_Greeting_person(Greeting g, EReference ref) {
        val model = g.eContainer as Model
        return Scopes.scopeFor(model.elements.filter(Person))
    }
}
```

**So my question is:**

In an obviously much more complex grammar, do I need to write all the individual scope-providers, to make the serialization work? Or is there some configuration option, that I'm missing?

Comment: @aphex Unfortunately, I don't work on an xtext project anymore, but the missing ResourceSet could be the problem. Sadly, you have to dig deep inside the EMF/Xtext sources to find out wtf is wrong... :( If you find out, please feel free to post the solution, others can benefit from this as well.

Answer (score 0):

what about adding the model to a dummy resource

```
va rs = injector.getInstance(ResourceSet)
val resource = rs.createResource(URI.createURI("dummy/test.mydsl"))
resource.contents += model
```

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reply directly to @Balazs Edes, but the solution track that @Christian Dietrich has given is right; here's an example on how to implement it:

Inject resourceset:

```
@Inject Provider<XtextResourceSet> rsProvider
```

Then create a resource:

```
val rs = rsProvider.get

val resource = rs.createResource(URI.createURI("dummy/test.dmodel"))
```

In a later step, before running serialize(), add the model to the resource:

```
resource.getContents.add(model)
```